# Table changing of data when sending it to a function in C

Tags: c, function

So I did write at first all of my functions in my main.
But it takes too much place so I tried to make header files and source files of my code.

But there the problem comes, when I send a table[x][y] from the main file to a function in an other file, the data of the table is like converted and it changes the values of the table, making it unusable.

I'm initially stroring caracters of numbers, like so : '0' or '1' or '2' ...
And when I print the values with `printf("%c", level[x][y]);` in the two functions, the main and the one from the other file, it first work in the main and it doesn't work properly in the second function.
It prints spaces or other caracters totally changed.

I tried also with `printf("%d", level[x][y]);` but it doesn't work as well. The results are different, in the first function it shows the caracter "code" and in the second it shows me like memory adresses but I'm not sure.

The orginal file read is like so (but there are 100 lines and 100 columns):

```
000000000000000
000000000100000
000000000000000
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define tx 100
#define ty 100
#include "function.h"

void fill_level(char *file, int level[tx][ty]){
    FILE *fichier=NULL;
    fichier = fopen(file, "r");
    int x, y;
    char buff = '0';
    if(fichier == NULL) printf("Erreur de lecture du fichier de niveau");
    else {
    for(y = 0;y < ty; y++){
        for(x = 0;x < tx; x++) {
            buff = fgetc(fichier);
            level[x][ty-y] = buff;
        }
    }
    }
    fclose(fichier);
}

int main() {

int level_1[tx][ty]={{0}};
fill_level("Level 1.txt", level_1);

int i, j;
    for(i = 0;i < ty;i++){
        for(j = 0;j < tx;j++){
            printf("%c", level_1[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

//then I call the function from the second file

summon_entity_level(level_1);

}
```

The second function parameters are :

```c
void summon_entity_level(int levelEnt[tx][ty]);
```

And the second function is :

```c
#define tx 100
#define ty 100

void summon_entity_level( int levelEnt[tx][ty]){

    int i, j;
    for(i = 0;i < ty;i++){
        for(j = 0;j < tx;j++){
            printf("%c", levelEnt[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I expect something like so (works in the main):

```
000000000000000
000000000100000
000000000000000
```

But I get somthing like this (in the second function from the other file):

```
`dyüm  áP░ ┴ C ð   0î
CIIC   ,aß@H I
```

Comment: What is `ty` and `tx`? Where are it's declaration/definition?

Comment: I could not understand first argument of your function. Is it a typo error?

Comment: tx and ty are defined values with ```#define tx 100``` for example, it corresponds to the size of the table

Comment: ```struct entity entity[ent]``` is a table struct I am using to do other things in my function but it doesnt interfer with what I am trying to do firts : read the table

Comment: I edited my question so it's clearer

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the code I posted in the Question is actually working, I was in fact working on an other code with more context and the context was interfering with the code I showed. I finally managed to make it work, thanks for the answers.
Here is what I am working on, it is a reproduction of Mario using SDL 2, that's why I called my table level, it is to store the level. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQpPj.png)